# Reading bytes from file to byte[] and converting to string

Tags: java, string, arrays, randomaccessfile

I'm currently working on a program that requires use of RandomAccessFile to write to files and then be able to read them back. 
My write function:
NAME, LOCATION, TYPE are final ints with the length of that type in bytes and are used to find where to write at. I've tried changing it so it just writes from wherever it left off but that would crash on me and not write at all.

```
for(int k=0;k<tab.length;k++){
            for(int l=0;l<tab[k].length;l++){
                int endRec = k*(NAME + LOCATION + TYPE); //used to get to the end of the last record written
                tables.seek(endRec);
                if(l==0){ 
                    tables.writeUTF(tab[k][l]); //writes just first attribute of record
                }
                else if(l==1){
                    tables.seek(endRec + NAME); //goes to end of last record, then goes to end of first attribute
                    tables.writeUTF(tab[k][l]); //writes second attribute
                }
                else if(l==2){
                    int hold = Integer.parseInt(tab[k][l]); //used to convert string from array to integer ie, "21" to 21
                    tables.seek(endRec + NAME + LOCATION); //goes to end of last record then past first two attributes
                    tables.writeInt(hold); //writes third and last attribute
                }
            }
        }
```

My read function(not finished it will read more just in testing mode now):

```
 RandomAccessFile readIn;
 byte[] Name = new byte[NAME];
 byte[] Location = new byte[LOCATION];
 byte[] TName = new byte[TNAME];

    try{
        readIn = new RandomAccessFile("sys_library.tab", "r");
        readIn.read(Name);
        readIn.read(Location);
        int readType = readIn.readInt();
        String readName = new String(Name, "UTF-8");
        String readLocation = new String(Location, "UTF-8");
        System.out.printf("%20s%132s%8s%n", readName, readLocation, readType);
        readIn.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

However when it reads in and outputs it is outputting white square boxes that can lead to the strings being cut off. Integers are printing fine it is just my strings that are messy. Is there a different method for converting byte[] to string?
An example is it outputting (square)(square)sys_library.ta , it should be just sys_library.tab but it is putting extra in.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the file you're reading?

Comment: I ended up getting it fixed. Had to change up how I was reading in. I read in characters and threw away the ones that were non-ascii.

Comment: Oh, good! For what it's worth, here's a regex pattern to check for ASCII characters `Pattern.compile("\\p{ASCII}*$");`